# Knockout generating two bootstrap carousels on the page, second carousel broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I use knockout to display two carousels on a page. My first carousel works just fine, the second one though, displays only the side navigation and breaks on click.

here's the code:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Languages">
    <div data-bind="attr: { id: 'image-carousel-' + Id() }" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators" data-bind="foreach: $root.mediaFiles">
            <li data-bind="attr: { 'data-target': '#image-carousel-' + $parent.Id(), 'data-slide-to': $index() }, css: { active: Name == $parent.Image() }"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner media-images" data-bind="foreach: $root.mediaFiles">
            <div class="item" data-bind="css: { active: Name == $parent.Image() }">
                <div class="text-center dark-carbon top-padding-sm bottom-padding-sm">
                    <img class="cursor-pointer pol-h-200" data-bind="attr: { src: Url }, click: function () { $root.selectImage(Name, $parent); }" alt="Media file" />
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <span data-bind="visible: Name == $parent.Image()">selected</span>
                    <span data-bind="visible: Name != $parent.Image()">click to select image</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" data-bind="attr: { href: '#image-carousel-' + Id() }" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" data-bind="attr: { href: '#image-carousel-' + Id() }" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: i cant see any link for the code

Comment: Share the data Languages observableArray has. We can help